# Reflecting replies to customer reviews on my website

Tags: wordpress, review

I want to reflect my replies that I write to customers after they have forwarded a review for a product on my website. It allows me to write the reply but it does not appear under the review on my home page.

I have researched but can't seem to find an answer to my question.